# No halt at breakpoints after update

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have been using WebStorm with Meteor/Angular2/TypeScript for several months now and debugging via the chrome plugin worked like a charm. But two days ago I updated WebStorm to version 2016.3.

Since then the debugger seems to work (like console output goes to the WebStorm console), but it is no longer halting on my breakpoints. I have checked my configurations and nothing seems to have changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by halting not halting on break points?

Comment: It is completely ignoring the break points I set. Execution is not interrupted.

Comment: Is your console open in browser?

Comment: Chrome console is closed and JetBrains IDE Support Plugin is running. I do see the browser console output in my Webstorm debugger console, so the connection is available.

Comment: Can you open the chrome console and try again?

Comment: Opening the chrome console stops the IDE Support Plugin and therefore debugging. That is an expected behavior.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket...